# Using Access VBA code, how do I replace words in a comment box using table columns to search for a set of words I want replaced?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to reference a table in access to replace words in a comment box. I would search for the words in column 1 and replace them with the words in column 2. I'm not sure how to properly name the columns to insert them in a replace function.

Here is an example of code I am trying to use,

```
Private Sub Replace_Click()

Dim bullet As String
Dim output As String

bullet = commentBox.Value
commentBox.Value = Replace(bullet, [tbl_name].column_name, [tbl_name].column_name)

End Sub
```

Comment: `dlookup` may help.  Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Edit question to provide sample data. How should expression know which record to pull replacement from?

Comment: My plan is to be able to type a paragraph into a text box.  Next I would click a button to abbreviate any words in that paragraph found in a table.  Column A of the table would have full words and Column B would have the abbreviation for that word.  I've seen VBA code for this in excel but I'm not sure how to write it for Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options to consider:

1. Open a recordset of the table, loop through records and execute Replace on each value. If value is in string it will be replaced, if it's not in string then nothing happens.

```
Sub SubAbb()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, sStr As String
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Word, Abb FROM Words")
sStr = Me.commentBox
Do While Not rs.EOF
    sStr = Replace(sStr, rs!Word, rs!Abb)
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
Me.commentBox = sStr
End Sub
```

2. Split string to an array, loop through array and do a DLookup on table. If abbreviation found, run Replace on the string. However, this presumes string has only words separated by single space, no punctuation or numbers or dates, which will complicate code.

```
Sub SubAbb()
Dim sStr As String, sAbb As String, sAry As Variant, x As Integer
sStr = Me.commentBox
sAry = Split(sStr, " ")
For x = 0 To UBound(sAry)
    sAbb = Nz(DLookup("Abb", "Words", "Word='" & sAry(x) & "'"), "")
    If sAbb <> "" Then sStr = Replace(sStr, sAry(x), sAbb)
Next
Me.commentBox = sStr
End Sub
```

Comment: I am still pretty new at writing VBA code.  Do I need to modify this code in any way to make it fit my database?  I tried the two options above and even tried changing some wording around but I'm still receiving errors.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: I am sure modification would be needed. You would have to use your object names for one. I don't know your db so really can't be specific. If you need more help, then edit question with attempted code and errors encountered. I had an error in DLookup expression which I have corrected.

Comment: You also need to be aware that all instances of a string would be replaced and Access is not case sensitive by default, so if word is "approximate" and you want to replace with "app", "Approximately" would be changed to "apply".

Comment: I was able to make it work using option 1 after rewriting some of the data to match my database.  Is there any way to remove the case sensitive in that replace function?  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You mean you want to add case sensitivity? Replace() has an optional Compare argument that can set case sensitivity with vbBinaryCompare parameter. For details see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/replace-function